# redirect external Google Sites URL with masking

Tags: redirect, cloaking

I would like to do this.  Create a hyperlink that when clicked masks the URL.

Example:

Displayed site: https://sites.google.com/mybusinesssite.com/customer1/packing
URL shows:      https://sites.google.com/mytravelsite.com/customer1/packing

I've done research but struck out.  Is this even possible to achieve either with PHP, JavaScript or some other method other than HTACCESS declarations?

Haven't tried anything as all research doesn't really address this particular problem.